# Where can I find directory containing symbolic versions of my app's shared libraries for using ndk-stack?

Tags: android, debugging, android-ndk

I am getting some tombstone crashes on my application and want to debug it:

To use ndk-stack, you first need a directory containing symbolic versions of your app's shared libraries. If you use the NDK build system (ndk-build), these shared-library files reside under $PROJECT_PATH/obj/local/, where  represents your device's ABI. By default, the system uses the armeabi ABI.

Comment: What you're asking is not clear - take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for this directory in Android Studio project, by default you will find it under `app/build/intermediates/binaries/debug/obj/`.